# Cannot show ads in Windows Universal app

Tags: windows-phone, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I created an app from Windows Universal (Windows 10) template and integrated Microsoft Advertising in the MainPage.
When I run the app, an error occured with message:

> Required capabilities are missing from manifest (AppxManifest.xml): internetClient

I'm sure in Package.AppxManifest checked both Internet (client) and Internet (client and server) but it still shows the above error when run app

Code put on MainPage.xaml:

```
<UI:AdControl Height="250" Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="AdControl" ErrorOccurred="AdControl_ErrorOccurred" HorizontalAlignment="Right" ApplicationId="xxx" AdUnitId="xxx" />
```

Comment: I've got an exactly same issue. If you use it with AdMediator, this 'capability' error will not occurred. But AdMediator is unstable to use... hmm.....

Comment: Did you make AdMediator to show ads? Can you provide sample code

Comment: Yes. As of MSDN saids, using AdMediator is a 'normal' way to show ads on UWP apps. You can follow this link to implement it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219682.aspx       But I have experienced the fatal issue with mediator like this guy, then I'm now trying to show ads without mediator.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f4039b2-22db-4f54-9a2f-7405553ca76e/

Answer (score 0):

which version of the Microsoft Advertising  SDK are you using ? It's recommended to use the Microsoft Universal Ad Client SDK v2.0.2 : 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/401703a0-263e-4949-8f0f-738305d6ef4b

Comment: I'm using AdControl drag from toolbox, not AdMediator. Can you provide sample code using AdMediator to show Microsoft Ads